# How to save .txt content into an array

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I have a list of words (some of them are colors, some of them are not) written in a .txt file.

I need to save these words into an array so that I can apply color to a grid later on. How do I turn this file into an array?

Comment: Hi Mariana. You forget to tell us which programming language you are using. Simply add a tag to your question.

Comment: Hi, What is the format of your file?